# GSON не десеарелезует поля объектов в Java

Tags: java, json, gson, десериализация

Использую Java 11 и IntelliJ IDEA 2019

Начну с того, что это происходит не со всеми классами. Например, десеарилацзия класса такого вида происходит нормально:

```
public class TimeWrapper {
    private int time = 0;

    // тут геттеры и сеттеры для time, не буду засорять ими вопрос
}
```

Если же я пытаюсь десеарелизовать, например, экземпляр такого класса:

```
public class TimerTaskTime extends ModifiedTimerTask {
    public TimerTaskTime(long period) {
        super(period);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeWrapper.setTime(timeWrapper.getTime() + 1);
        System.out.println(">>>>> " + timeWrapper.getTime());
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class ModifiedTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private long currentTimeMillis;
    private long launchTimeMillis;
    private long periodMillis;

    public ModifiedTimerTask(long periodMillis) {
        setPeriodMillis(periodMillis);
    }

    // тут геттеры и сеттеры всех полей этого класса, не буду засорять ими вопрос
}
```

то ничего не десеарилизуется. Все поля объекта остаются со стандартными значениями, хотя при сериализации объект был сериализован как:

```
{
  "value": {
    "currentTimeMillis": 1603871358784,
    "launchTimeMillis": 1603871358210,
    "periodMillis": 1000,
    "lock": {},
    "state": 1,
    "nextExecutionTime": 1603871359210,
    "period": -1000
  }
}
```

Попытался найти ответ в других вопросах стековерфлоу, но нашел там лишь совет "возможно у вас не совпадают имена сериализованных полей и полей объекта". Как видно, имена сходятся(хотя у геттеров и сеттеров у всех полей у которых 2 слова или более, поля с большой буквы, например getPeriodMillis())

Я сериализую объекты так:

```
// все объекты записываются поочередно в json.json в корневой папке проекта
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("json.json");
// GlobalVar.GSON хранит объект Gson; timerTaskTime хранит в себе TimerTaskTime, описанный ранее
GlobalVar.GSON.toJson(timerTaskTime, fileWriter);
// ...сериализация других объектов...
```

Я десеарелизую объекты так:

```
JsonReader fileReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("json.json"));
// set() потому что timerTaskTime хранит AtomicReference на TimerTaskTime
timerTaskTime.set(GlobalVar.GSON.fromJson(fileReader, TimerTaskTime.class));
// ...десеарилазция прочих объектов...
```

Так вот сам вопрос. Что не так? Почему объект десеарилизуется с пустыми полями?

[image: десеарилзованный с пустыми полями объект]

Comment: Думаю придется ответить на свой вопрос - проблема была только из за моей невнимательности. Дело в том, что я хранил в timerTaskTime AtomicReference на TimerTaskTime. Также и сериализовал его. Десереализовал(пытался) я его как TimerTaskTimer. С такой задачей GSON, разумеется, не справился.

Answer (score 3):

Вы путаете `JsonReader` и `Gson` - это два разных парсера. Чтобы спарсить с помощью Gson надо сделать примерно так:

```
 TimerTaskTime timerTask = GlobalVar.GSON.fromJson(new FileReader("json.json"), TimerTaskTime.class);
```

`JsonReader` здесь не причем.

Comment: А разве не стоит аннотацию Serializable вешать? А то в Android если не повесить аннотацию и использовать Proguard, то ваше приложение будет падать?

Comment: Я про Фому, а вы про Ерему... Вопрос был не об этом совершенно

Comment: Спасибо, что нашли эту ошибку в коде. И хотя проблема была в другом(в моей невнимательности), плюсик все равно поставлю